# How to write a generalized trigger for a set of tables?

Tags: oracle, triggers

My aim is to create triggers to few tables upon updation or deletion of entries from these tables.
The trigger should enter the name and columns of the corresponding updated/deleted table to another user table.
Instead of writing individual triggers for each table is it possible to write a single trigger ?

Comment: *"is it possible to write a single trigger ?"* No. Triggers belong to a single table. Also this approach to journalling is a common but savage anti-pattern. A separate history table whose projection matches that of the transaction table is easier to work with and more performative too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of writing individual triggers for each table is it possible to write a single trigger?

[TL;DR] No

---

The [`CREATE TRIGGER` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B) is:

> ### Syntax
>
> #### create_trigger ::=
>
> [image: create trigger syntax diagram]
>
> #### plsql_trigger_source ::=
>
> [image: PL/SQL trigger source syntax]
>
> #### simple_dml_trigger ::=
>
> [image: Simple DML Trigger syntax]
>
> #### dml_event_clause ::=
>
> [image: DML Event clause syntax]

As you can see from the syntax diagram, a `CREATE TRIGGER` for simple DML will be in the format:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
  AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON table_name
```

The syntax requires a single table/view identifier to be specified for each trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As @MT0 points out, a trigger is tied to a table so you'd need to create separate triggers for each table.

On the other hand, if you really want to do this, you can write code that dynamically generates the triggers you want for a number of different tables.  This is generally a lot more work initially but if you really want to create a bunch of different triggers with the same basic logic, that initial upfront investment may be reasonable.

You could, for example, write a bit of dynamic SQL that creates the triggers you want based on the data dictionary.  See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=546f70ccbf911571590a22dd9d63442b) for an example.  I haven't spent any time on niceties like making the generated trigger code particularly easy for a human to read or on fleshing out the requirements on what you actually want to write to the log table.  For example, most people would want to check whether the `:new` value of a column was different from the `:old` value of a column to see whether it was actually changed rather than using the `updating` function.  I'd also guess that your actual requirements involve writing the actual values that were updated or deleted to the log table which gets complicated based on things like the data types you support and the structure of your log table.

Personally, I always look a bit askance at this sort of requirement.  Oracle has lots of built-in functionality that make repetitive triggers less than ideal.  For example, I'd much rather enable [flashback data archive](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/flashback-data-archive-fda-enhancements-12cr1) for whatever tables you want to track than to deal with the overhead of a bunch of triggers.